# Visually Better Mathematic Subscripts

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

When writing mathematics in LaTeX and text more than a symbol long is placed in subscripts then it is not appeared in a nice way. Especially if the subscript is a whole word.

A better way is to be used inside a `\text{}` command but although the text itself is better-looking it doesn't match the math font as the one is usually italic and the other is not.

How can I have subscripts with text properties but matching the math font so to make the two indistinguishable?

Also is there a better way to create nice long subscripts?

Comment: Could you provide some examples?

Comment: Well, if the subscript is a word, it *should* be written with the `text` font for clarity. If every part of a complex formula looks the same, the formula readily becomes unreadable. That's why French mathematical typography uses \upshape for Greek letters, to have a greater variety in complex formulae. Now if you insist, use `\textit`.

Comment: @Werner I don't have any examples I don't even know what the best practices are.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for that, I didn't know it. I like typography tips :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this solution appeals to you.  To »match the math font«, if you like, replace `\textnormal{#1}` by `\textnormal{\textit{#1}}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

{
  \catcode`"=\active
  \gdef"#1{{\textnormal{#1}}}
}
\mathcode`"="8000

\begin{document}

$X_"{Hello}$

\end{document}
```

[image]